# $k$-power of a given bidiagonal matrix and asymptotic behaviour

Tags: matrices, asymptotics, matrix-calculus

> Let
>
> $$ P = \begin{bmatrix} 
>          0 & d & 0 & 0 & \ldots  & 0 \\
>          0 & r & d & 0 & \ldots  & 0 \\
>          0 & 0 & r & d & \ldots  & 0 \\
>          \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & d \\ 
>          0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots  & r \\
>          \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> be a square $n \times n$ matrix. Give a general formula for the elements of $P^k$, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and analyze the asymptotic behavior of $P^k x$ for $k \to \infty $
>
> Hint: $x_i^k \approx k^{n-i} \lambda^k c_i (x) $ for big $k$ where $ c_i (x) $ is constant.

I would be grateful for any hints.

Comment: The first column seems wrong. Are you sure about the question?

Comment: Yes, its from this paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235696079_Models_of_population_dynamics_and_their_applications_in_genetics (special case of telomere shortening model - page 7).

Comment: On page 7, parameters $r$ and $d$ have subscripts. In other words, there are $2n$ parameters, rather than $2$. And the matrix is $(n+1) \times (n+1)$.

Comment: Rodrigo, thank you for vigilance. As you can see I wrote "special case" of model I reference to (I mean d_i = d for all i from 1 to n). Dimension of matrix ( n times n or (n+1) times (n+1) ) makes no difference - its only important that matrix is square.